# Php crashes while receiving data, How to resolve this?

Tags: php, nginx, drupal, drupal-8, nginx-config

I manually configured PHP and Nginx and installed Drupal 8.
It worked good with no problems.

Then I started receive data to my Drupal 8 site 3000 packets of data per minute but after receiving around 500 packets of data the PHP crash.

I changed the  following in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 2000M

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 60

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time = -1

; Maximum input variable nesting level
; http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level
;max_input_nesting_level = 64

; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
;max_input_vars = 1000

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = -1M
```

and in ngnix.conf

```
http{

client_max_body_size 0m;

server{
}
}
```

and still after changing this the PHP crashes.

when I use nginx error log

```
[error] 8180#1472: *2532 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: IP address, server: localhost, request: "GET /clientview HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "IP address", 
[error] 8180#1472: *3545 WSASend() failed (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while sending request to upstream, client: IP address, server: localhost, request: "POST /entity/node/?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "IP address"
```

How can resolve this?

Comment: PHP is not crashing likely. Your web server is crashing. PHP gives errors, have any?

Comment: `memory_limit = -1M` ??? Either you put `memory_limit = 1M` or `memory_limit = -1`

Comment: edited the errors I received from nginx logs. PHP does not show any error!!

Comment: @MacSim What about the client_max_body_size,  and post_max_size??